# DJISDK didUpdateDatabaseDownloadProgress

Tags: ios, dji-sdk

I found that DJISDK requires:

1. the app user to agree bluetooth usage
2. update database and download it

then, the app can be registered (provided DJISDKAppKey is set properly in info.plist and so on).

My question is, why DJISDK need to update database and download it again?
What's the content of database?

Answer (score 0):

It's a "fly safe" database, containing data about areas where one is not allowed to fly.

If the database is not included in the package (to reduce package size), it must be downloaded once the application starts.

The method you mentioned is for monitoring the progress of the download (because the database is not very small, downloading it can take some time).